# Google Analytics Reporting API dimension Ad Content ID

Tags: api, google-analytics-api

I have found on Google Analytics API page that there is an Ad Content field.  However I am wondering whether there is an Ad Content ID field for the Google Analytics Reporting API as a dimension?

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to pulling AdWords data via the Google Analytics Reporting API, some of the information is limited. For example, you cannot pull calls from ads using the Analytics Reporting API.

I've never pulled calls from ads data before using API's, but I believe you can use the AdWords API, so you may have to use the Adwords API to grab the data you need.

I live by Google's Dimensions and Metrics Explorer:
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/

If I ever need to grab a dimension or metric name, I look here.

Looking at AdWords data specifically, there are a number of different dimensions you can include into your object query when you ping the API. I'm a little out of my depth with Adwords so I could be wrong, but I don't believe I see an Ad Content ID available to be used as a dimension in the Analytics Reporting API.